# can't show greek letters in browser

Tags: html, css, encoding, character-encoding, metadata

I am developing a website using html and css and i can't see greek letters.Instead of this,i only see symbols.
i have the following line in my html file:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
```

I also tried:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=windows-1253" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=ibm869" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=ibm737" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=iso-8859-7"/>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=x-mac-greek"/>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=x-EBCDIC-GreekModern "/>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=x-EBCDIC-Greek "/>
```

Nothing worked!
p.s. I tried this in Firefox and Internet Explorer

Comment: Are you sure your file is saved as UTF-8?

Comment: Are you sure your font actually _has_ the Greek letters you'd like to display?

Comment: how can i see if a)my file is saved as UTF-8 and b)if my font has the Greek letters i'd like to display?

Comment: Haven't you tried `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf8"/>`?

Comment: @Sheric I tried this.Question EDITED

Comment: Open your file in Notepad, File -> Save As from the top menu, then there's a drop down in the save as dialogue where you can select character encoding.  Make sure UTF-8 is chosen rather than ANSI

Comment: How did you create the HTML file, and how did you enter the Greek letters?

Comment: You can check the file encoding with closing and opening it again in notepad++. Please check it and let us know the result.

Comment: @John It worked in some files completely,in others it worked not completely and it didn't worked in  some others.I have 6 html files for the same website

Comment: Some letters are ok,some others are not.I think the problem comes from the fact that ,yesterday, when i was trying to fix this problem,i changed something about the encoding in Notepad++. Do i have to write again all the letters from the beginning or can i change something in Notepad++ to fix my "broken" letters?

Comment: "Broken letters":I mean that now symbols are appearing in Notepad++(eg in html paragraphs) instead of greek letters which i wrote.eg this  ��������� was greek letters before

Comment: I changed the character sets to greek in Notepad++ and this is the reason that i see symbols instead of greek letters now that you helped me fix the problem.Also when i try to change the character sets again,Notepad++ warns me that i shoud save the current modification and that i will lose undo ability

Comment: @John You can write your comment as the answer to be selected for the right answer!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As per your comment

Open your file in Notepad, File -> Save As from the top menu, then there's a drop down in the save as dialogue where you can select character encoding. Make sure UTF-8 is chosen rather than ANSI

Once the file has been saved as UTF-8 then you should have no problems adding Greek letters, (or Russian, Hebrew, Japanese or whatever)

Answer (score 3):

Per the comments / answers here, you'll need to check to see what the encoding is set to. Best way would be to see exactly how the server is sending it by inspecting the Response Headers. You can do this with Developer Tools on most browsers.

I just inspected the headers for this page using Chrome:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you check the file without the local server which many times that causes the problem. I had the same problem and opened the file from the browser directly and worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem while developing a page in greek. The problem wasn't the utf-8. I had to correct the CSS.

Regards,

Nick

Comment: This doesn't add any value to the already existing answers. Please, [read this guide to answering Stack Overflow questions.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)