# rijndael aes turkish character not displayed (classic asp)

Tags: encryption, asp-classic, base64, character, rijndaelmanaged

```
Response.LCID = 1055  
Response.Codepage = 65001 
Response.Charset = "utf-8"
knm = "ışöçü"
    sss = "asd"
    enc = AESEncyptString(knm,sss)
    dec = AESDecyptString(enc,sss)

    response.write(dec)

    Results = ?????
```

I tried it with Base64.

```
   knm = Base64encode("ışöçü")
    sss = "asd"
    enc = AESEncyptString(knm,sss)
    dec = AESDecyptString(enc,sss)

    response.write(Base64decode(dec))

    Results = isocu
```

Turkish characters appear as "???". I tried it with Base64, but it didn't happen again.I'm trying to encrypt with Rijdnael AES. How can i solve this problem? (Sorry, I hope I told you right. My English is not very good. :))

Comment: Are your files actually saved with utf-8 encoding.  See my answer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15438046/cant-show-greek-letters-in-browser/15439145#15439145

Comment: VBScript doesn't natively support Unicode. You need to work around that using Streams. See questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4125778/unicode-to-utf-8

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio File-> Save as -> Save with encoding...(under Save button) ->
Select UTF-8 or Turkish (Windows) - Codepage 1254

[image: first]

[image]

[image]